# CSS merging with PHP

Tags: php, css

I found this on a website,

css_loader.php

```
<?php
// First of all send css header
header("Content-type: text/css");

// Array of css files
$css = array(
    'main.css',
    'menu.css',
    'content.css'
);

// Loop the css Array
foreach ($css as $css_file) {

    // Load the content of the css file 
    $css_content = file_get_contents($css_file);

    // print the css content
    echo $css_content;
}
?>
```

Add CSS to the page

```
<link href="css_loader.php" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It looks very logical but when i applied it to my page, it didnt work.

is that possible to merge CSS files with this way ?

Comment: Of course it is possible.  Why didn't it work for you?  No errors?  Nothing?

Comment: What "doesn't work" mean? when you access `css_loader.php` directly from your browser and save the ourcome, what do you see?

Comment: How did you apply it to your page? Headers don't work after you already output to the browser. Also CSS needs to be put in the `<head>` section not the body so it makes all the difference about how you applied this.

Comment: i can see all CSS content but my page looked like has no CSS somehow. no error :S

Comment: What do you think of adding a newline char after the echo? Just to make sure the rules are well separated.

Comment: use inspect element in firefox or chrome to see what CSS is being applied

Comment: is your `css_loader.php` file in the same path as the page that links it?

Comment: @Umbrella concatinating data (eg css files) reduces the number of requests to the server and reduces the load time of a web page. Whether or not this is significant when taking into account the time needed to concatenate the files is a question I'd be interested in knowing the answer to.

Comment: @PhillHealey I imagine the trade off varies by environment and size of files.  You could get best of both worlds by doing the concat in a deploy script, or a first run script (such as a 404 handler that does the concat and saves to the requested css file for conventional loading on next request).

Comment: @Umbrella 404 handler? Please explain...

Comment: 404 handler just-in-time resource building: I do this with real-time image resizing (such as thumbnails). The idea is, you set your page/app to call for the generated resource (such as combined CSS, or smaller image) at a static URL, then configure the server's 404 error document to a script which, based on the requested URL, builds the requested file, saves it at the requested location, sets the response code to 200, then returns it to the browser. The next request for the same resource will find the generated file and return it without a 404 event. Re-deploying should delete expired files.

Comment: @PhillHealey ^ (forgot to tag)

Comment: @Umbrella Ah, ok. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have an mistake in your code, here's the correct code:

```
<?php
// First of all send css header
header("Content-type: text/css");

// Array of css files
$css = array(
    'main.css',
    'menu.css',
    'content.css'
);

// Prevent a notice
$css_content = '';

// Loop the css Array
foreach ($css as $css_file) {
    // Load the content of the css file 
    $css_content .= file_get_contents($css_file);
}

// print the css content
echo $css_content;
?>
```

And I hope the files are in the same folder. Perhaps you should  use `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the relative path to your files.

Comment: yeah fixed this. but still CSS doesnt apply to page.

Comment: I have tested this case. Perhaps you have an error in your php file. call the file direkt and test it. When one of the file is missing you get Warning: file_get_contents(main.css) and into an text/css stream the browser can't handle it.

Answer (score 12):

Stoney has shown you your error .... now for a more improved version

```
        header('Content-type: text/css');
        ob_start("compress");
        function compress($buffer) {
            /* remove comments */
            $buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
            /* remove tabs, spaces, newlines, etc. */
            $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $buffer);
            return $buffer;
        }

        /* your css files */
        include('main.css');
        include('menu.css');
        include('content.css');
        ob_end_flush();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php

// Array of css files
$css = array(
 'first.css',
 'second.css'
);

$mergeCSS = "";
// Loop the css Array
foreach ($cssas $css_file) {
    // Load the content of the css file 
    $mergeCSS.= file_get_contents($css_file);
}

// Remove comments also applicable in javascript
$mergeCSS= preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $mergeCSS);

// Remove space after colons
$mergeCSS= str_replace(': ', ':', $mergeCSS);

// Remove whitespace
$mergeCSS= str_replace(array("\n", "\t", '  ', '    ', '    '), '', $mergeCSS);

//Generate Etag
$genEtag = md5_file($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

// call the browser that support gzip, deflate or none at all, if the browser doest      support compression this function will automatically return to FALSE
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');

// call the generated etag
header("Etag: ".$genEtag); 

// Same as the cache-control and this is optional
header("Pragma: public");

// Enable caching
header("Cache-Control: public ");

// Expire in one day
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 86400 ) . ' GMT');

// Set the correct MIME type, because Apache won't set it for us
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

// Set accept-encoding
header('Vary: Accept-Encoding');

// Write everything out
echo($mergeCSS);

?>
```

This code also compatible for merging javascript

Comment: Change the content type from text/javascript to text/css

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this class for such needs, it can render the output and compress it, later i can add write a file of the end results, [link here](http://www.littleblogthing.com/snippets/php-classes/css-merge-and-compress-class)

Answer (score 0):

hey have you checked if your server appends a few lines to your code (for example an analytics code) . if so you must add a rule in .htaccess that stops the server for adding lines to your code. this can be done by adding this to .htaccess - "php_value auto_append_file none" without quotes of course . i hope this helps