# How to merge two files in php while replacing the contents?

Tags: php

I wanna know how to merge two files in php such that one final file is generated and have both changes,

example :

style.css

```
#mydiv{
   background:white;
   color:black;
}
```

and

style2.css

```
#mydiv{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

and

final.css

```
#mydiv{
   background:white;
   color:black;
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

So I want the `final.css` in output after merging `style.css` and `style2.css`,,

Note : CSS file is not my point, its just for example,, I want to do it with any kind of file Like merging files with both versions.

Another Example :

file1.js

```
var x=90;
var y=50;
var z=x+y;
```

file2.js

```
var z=x+y;
var yx=500;
```

and

output.js

```
var x=90;
var y=50;
var z=x+y;
var yx=500;
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the use case you mentioned, what is the need for merging, you can discard/delete style1.css and rename style2.css to final.css

Comment: will they id always be same?

Comment: can you say what your real purpose? if you use both style.css and style2.css in html it will be always like final.css. because css will replace the old style in the same parameter

Comment: please explain more, and give another example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9862961/2218253 Answers your question with a working example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS merging with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862904/css-merging-with-php)

Comment: its not css merging,, Thats just an example,, 

I want to do it with any kind of file

Comment: can you give another example file? dont delete your previous example. we need know the spesific condition and situation